# Undeleting an answer doesn't preserve the upvotes and downvotes correctly - Bug in Reputation Calculation

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, voting, deleted-answers

I deleted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523074/jquery-loaded-file-still-in-cache/48525037#48525037) which had **1 upvote** and **2 downvotes** (Total reputation -> 10-4 = 6), so my reputation decreased by 6. Then after undeleting the answer my reputation should increase by 6, but instead it further decreased by 2 because overall votes on the answer was -1. I had to again delete that answer. I am assuming this is a bug on Stack Overflow. If not please explain the reason behind this.

Comment: The 6 reputation you lost was on a completely different answer. You can see it in your reputation history as long as "show removed posts" is checked at the bottom.

Comment: Usually waiting a bit to dismiss cache problems helps

Comment: @animuson I have seen the reputation history, there is no mention about the loss of 6 reputation.

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of your reputation history, and click the checkbox next to "show removed posts" to make those events appear.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks  a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. As its current state is, it has **only 1 downvote** without an upvote (I have 10k on SO so I can see it). <s>It's very simple: the upvote and one of the two downvotes are gone, somehow.</s> As animuson says, it's not this very answer that caused the loss the the 6 rep. It's something else which confused you.

Do note that you earn or lose reputation **immediately** when your post is voted up or down, but when you delete a post, related reputation is **not** reverted immediately. There's a window of up to 5 minutes before the rep recalc is done. So it's very likely that you had deleted another answer (as animuson said), whose related recalc was done **at the point** when you deleted this very answer, which created an illusion that the deletion of this answer lost you 6 rep.

[image]

By the way, just write a few more good posts and you'll reach 1k on SO, which will enable you to check the number of upvotes and downvotes separately.

Comment: Thats what the bug is, somehow 1 upvote and 1 downvote is gone on deleteing the answer. SO is just preserving the total votes (upvotes-downvotes), not the exact numbers of each, which in my view is a bug.

Comment: That post only ever had the one downvote - there are no other votes ever cast to it. So none of them disappeared or anything. The OP is just mistaken which answer actually lost them the reputation. It wasn't this one.

Comment: @mav3n See what animuson (a member of the CM team) says.

Comment: Then how on deleting the answer (with -1 reputation) for the first time decreased my reputation by 6 instead of increasing by 2?

Comment: @mav3n The loss of 6 is caused by another answer. It's just a coincidence. Note that for deleted posts, reputation is not reverted immediately. There's a maximum of 5 minutes before the system recalculates your reputation.

Comment: @mav3n It didn't. You first deleted that answer back on Jan 30. And you gained 2 rep by deleting it, just as you gained 2 reputation back by redeleting it today.